# Error output from attempt to compile contains information I cannot correlate with input code

Tags: gcc, output

Example: `myprog.c:(.text+0x18): undefined reference to 'prog.new'`

If `.text+0x18` is supposed to reference the line that is in error, how can I interpret the `.text` and the `+0x18`.

I understand the `0x18 = 24d`, but nothing at that line references the `prog.new`.

It isn't a line number, nor an offset from the beginning of the line!

What the heck is it?

Thanks, Derick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a location inside the `.c` file, but in the `.o` file (even though it says "myprog.c" and not "myprog.o"). `.text+0x18` means "the 18th byte after the start of the text section", the text section being the part of the object file that contains the executable code.

If you're getting locations like that, that means that the object file does not contain any debug information, so the linker can't reconstruct the line and column number from the byte number. If you compile with debug symbols (`-g`), you should get proper line numbers instead.